# How can I add labels to a plot?

Tags: plotting

I have created five lines in a plot.

```
Plot[Table[1 + (k - 1)*Sin[theta]^2, {k, 0, 2, 0.5}], {theta, 0, 
Pi/2}, PlotRange -> {{0, Pi/2}, {0, 2}}]
```

And I want to add five labels for them each other.I used PlotLabels \
such as this :

```
PlotLabels -> {"a=0", "a=0.5", "a=1.0", "a=1.5", "a=2.0"}
```

But I get a picture with only one label. I want to get fives of each other.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/831646?

Answer (score 5):

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[1 + (k - 1)*Sin[theta]^2, {k, 0, 2, 0.5}], {theta, 0, Pi/2}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, Pi/2}, {0, 2}}, PlotLabels -> {"a=0", "a=0.5", "a=1.0", "a=1.5", "a=2.0"}]
```

[image]

In response to your comment,

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[1 + (k - 1)*Sin[theta]^2, {k, 0, 2, 0.5}], {theta,
   0, Pi/2}, PlotRange -> {{0, Pi/2}, {0, 2}}, 
 PlotLabels -> {Subscript["I", 3]/Subscript["I", 1] == 0, "a=0.5", 
   "a=1.0", "a=1.5", "a=2.0"}]
```

[image]

Comment: That is great. But when I change "a" to "Subscript[I, 3]/Subscript[I, 1]", it does not work. How can I solve it?